# Django+React: What is the bet way to properly implement authentication and security on API requests from React to Django backend

Tags: django, reactjs, session, django-rest-framework

I am working on a `Django+React` project. My React app is my `only UI renderer` (which means no template or any markup is being served by Django), while my Django app is only used for `serving APIs` for me to access my database resources.

On a particular React page, I have `login` and `test` buttons that send requests to a `DRF API` in my Django backend.

**Login API View**

```
class AuthLogin(generics.GenericAPIView):
    serializer_class = LoginSerializer
    authentication_classes = [SessionAuthentication]
    permission_classes = ()

    def get(self, request):
        user = request.user
        if not user and not user.is_authenticated or user.is_anonymous:
            return Response(
                {
                    "status": True,
                    "message": "Login page accessed"
                }, status=status.HTTP_200_OK
            )
        else:
            return Response(
                {
                    "status": False,
                    "message": "You are currently logged in"
                }, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST
            )

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        res = []
        res_stat = status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=False)
        validated_data = serializer.validated_data

        if validated_data:
            user = dj_auth(username=request.data.get('username'),
                           password=request.data.get('password'))

            if user and user.is_authenticated and not user.is_anonymous:
                auth_login(request, user)
                res_stat = status.HTTP_200_OK
                res = {
                    "status": True,
                    "message": "Login successful!",
                    "login": {
                        "date_time": timezone.now(),
                        "user": {
                            'id': user.id,
                            'first_name': user.first_name,
                            'last_name': user.last_name,
                            'email': user.email,
                        }
                    }
                }
            else:
                res_stat = status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED
                res = {
                    "status": False,
                    "message": "Invalid username and/or password"
                }
        else:
            res_stat = status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED
            res = {
                "status": False,
                "message": "Invalid username and/or password"
            }
        return Response(res, status=res_stat)
```

**Test API View**

```
class Test(APIView):
    authentication_classes = [SessionAuthentication]
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if request.user and request.user.is_authenticated and not request.user.is_anonymous:
            return Response({
                "test": "coolsss",
                "user": request.user.id
            }, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
        else:
            return Response({
                "error": "Mind to login first?"
            }, status=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED)
```

So far so good in terms of Django+React integration on the above APIs. However, I noticed a security issue and I'm not sure completely how to move on from this.

I did the test in an incognito browser window. But, I also tested it in `Postman`. What I noticed was I already closed my incognito browser before testing on to Postman using the same `csrftoken` and `sessionid` cookies. When I closed the browser, I assume the session is destroyed since it was in incognito.

Now when I run the same in Postman, the `test` endpoint still authenticating, recognizes the user, and returns the positive response. I'm not sure if that is supposed to happen, and what approach shall be used to resolve this.

One sample scenario I see where this would be a nightmare is say Kate logs in and leaves her workstation for a minute. Her workmate John sneaks in to her browser and steals the `csrftoken` and `sessionid` cookie values of her current session.

Kate came back and for some reason closed her browser. John, using Postman on his own computer, made some POST request to an API which Kate is authorized to access using the token and sessionid he stole.

With this problem in `session/cookie-based` authentication, I am considering implementing `token-based` authentication instead, even if the `login` view is more appropriate to be authenticated by a server session and csrftoken cookie.

However, if I use token-based, I would also be storing that token in local storage so React will have the knowledge that the user is still logged in and for it to use that token for subsequent requests. But then again, a geek can always go to dev tool and sneak into that token value in the local storage.

I am so stuck at how I should properly implement authentication and security in the backend, while keeping the frontend of the user's login state.

Answer (score 1):

Token-based (JWT for example) is the go-to option for integrating a server-side service to a client-side app. And as for the problem you are facing, the simplest option would be adding an expire option to the token which still might not be the solution to all scenarios.

The fact is that when you create a client-side app, the client has control and you can't do much about it. protecting the token is the same as protecting a password that users should be thinking about. The most you can do is to make it harder for someone else to be able to simply take the token and use it somewhere else.

You can make multiple tokens with different specifications that the client-side has to generate and if all of them match, then you can serve the request. but again, that just makes it harder for someone else to duplicate the request not impossible.

If it was a compiled app that was hard to decompile and with the combination of some methods like using some certificate file that is also securely stored in the client's system, you could be more sure about the safety of your request but JS is too simple to read and duplicate.

Comment: Actually I've ady integrated `django knox authentication` which handles token management for me. But if I switch to using cookie-based session authentication, would it at least be good to rely on the existence of `sessionid` cookie for telling my React app whether a user is logged in or not and perform the appropriate routing?

Comment: What I meant was on React I would have something like `!cookie.get('sessionid') ? <LoginPage /> : <Dashboard />`... I know if I remove the cookie via dev tools, that will bring me back to login page even if I'm logged in. But is this approach somehow okay or totally unacceptable?

Comment: session ids are not really meant to be used as a token for your web client and they are stored as cookies which you might not choose to do so. while with tokens, you have more freedom to decide how they should be generated and how to be stored. I actually used Knox for a lot of my projects and I can recommend it.

Comment: Thanks a lot man! This is a confirmation I was looking for to know if my choice to use `Knox` is great. I also thing Token-auth is best for this use case as I am implementing client-server setup, React being my client. I guess Im gonna just stick to my knox implementation instead of switching to `SessionAuthentication` as it is giving me a lot of headache. Also I just found out that no matter how you try to prevent to hide the tokens, if it gets compromised by user's negligence, there is less you can do about it as the developer.

Comment: I was saying so as I conducted a test onTwitter. I made a tweet and examine the API request it made. I found out about important request headers such as `Bearer token`, `csrf token`, `auth token`; took these values and made a separate request via `Postman` in *another computer*, checked my Twitter account and it was made.

Comment: @Michael glad I could help.